# Wrap unwrapped textNode using regex in arbitrary HTML structure

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I have pages with HTML that look like this:

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <h2>Some Title</h2>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now I need to have the first Lorem ipsum text wrapped in `<p></p>` tags aswell. Is there a way to detect this and do it with regex?
I would be using regex to make these changes directly in the database.

Comment: With javascript its possible

Comment: Can't you select with Regex everything between `</h2>` and the first `<p>` ?
What language are you using here? is this in happening in the server?

Comment: You'd probably better use a parser instead. It's just a `TextNode` just under whatever the root of all those elements is.

Comment: @vsync I can't do that because above is just an example, and the tags change all the time throughout the page.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Could I get an example please? Much thanks.

Comment: Then why didn't you explicitly shared in your post this beneficial information you just revealed in your last comment?

Comment: @deoncagadoes how?

Comment: @turtlehamster you didn't specify a language.

Comment: @vsync my bad! Don't see a way to edit my post tho.

Comment: @turtlehamster click [edit] <-- here

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca javascript

Comment: Before you decide on regex, study this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: You want remove the before text "Lorem ipsum" ?

Comment: @vsync can you give me a regex example to select everything between </h2> and the first <p> ?

Comment: @deoncagadoes no, they need to wrap it between `<p>` and `</p>`.

Comment: @turtlehamster i have script who gets text and make a new element <p> with this text. You want ? Warning: I don't know how to remove another before text without elements.

Comment: On further inspection, this is no easy task (at least, not with the info you gave). You need one of two things to make this possible: a defined structure *or* some sort of anchor. A defined structure would allow you to traverse the nodes until you find the one that you know contains the TextNode you're interested in, and then wrap it in a paragraph. An anchor would allow you to use a regex or some such to do what deon suggests in their answer. Unfortunately, you said the html around the text may change, so there's nothing really you could use to tell "this is definitely the text I want"

Comment: **Unless** you know that the text will **always** be contained in `div.row>div.col-md-12` (the "structure" I'm talking about in the previous comment), in which case an easy solution can be devised.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca yes, that's always the structure. The only thing that changes is <h2> and sometimes there is no second paragraph, just plain text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your structure is fixed it's just a matter of

1. Finding the first non-empty `TextNode`
2. Creating a `p` element
3. Substituting the text node with the paragraph inside the parent node.

I made the paragraphs green so you can see the effect. Just click the "Wrap" button to see it in action.

```js
function wrap() {
  let div = document.querySelector('div.row>div.col-md-12');    // get the container
  for (let i = 0; i < div.childNodes.length; i++) {             // loop through children
    let n = div.childNodes[i];
    if (n.nodeName == "#text" && n.textContent.trim() !== '') { // children found!
      let p = document.createElement('p');                      // create a `p` element
      p.textContent = n.textContent;                            // put the original text inside
      n.parentNode.replaceChild(p, n);                          // swap!
      break;                                                    // we're done here
    }
  }
}
```

```css
p {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <h2>Some Title</h2>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
  </div>
</div>
<button onclick="javascript:wrap()">Wrap</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I used regex search, and when find the string, make a child element of class `col-md-12` and removed another string without elements!

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h2>Some Title</h2>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    <script>

        var string = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML;

        var regex = /Lorem ipsum[a-zA-Z0-9_ _,_.]*/g;

        var save = regex.exec(string)[0];
        document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML.replace(save, "");
        var first = document.createElement("p");
        var text = document.createTextNode(save);
        first.appendChild(text);

        document.getElementsByClassName("col-md-12")[0].appendChild(first);

    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: I will try this out now, thank you for the efforts. Will let you know how it goes.